# Selenium Python: How to close the overlay by clicking on the svg element

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I am looking for a way to click on the svg cross to close overlaying welcome window. I managed to go through login and authorization but this cross is getting me crazy.

Code trials:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "jss109"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//svg[@class='jss109']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[aria-hidden="True"]')).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "JSS109"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='jss109']/*[name()='svg']")))
```

Error massage: TimeoutException: Message:

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Another snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL of the app?

Comment: Doesn't looks like the mentioned `<svg>` is overlaying welcome window. Can you cross check once?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't share the web url - it's a internal corporate site.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium i mean welcome window overlays main website and can be closed only by clicking this cross.

Comment: @Paulina Makes sense, but I'm still not sure if the indicated `<svg>` is of the X sign because of it's properties. Can cross check just one last time?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium hm not sure if it helps but I added other screenshot to the post, please check.

Comment: @Paulina Yeap, seems you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the *`X`* icon you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 svg.jss109[viewBox]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[.//span[starts-with(., 'Welcome to new')]]//*[name()='svg' and @class][@viewBox]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I tried CSS_SELECTOR and it works!:) Can you share any description why to use class above(like here-h2)?

Comment: The `<svg>` is indeed within the `<h2>`, so it's always a better idea to construct a precise locator. Now with _xpath_ I was easily able to identify the required `<h2>` with respect to the text _`Welcome to new`_, where as for the _CSS_SELECTOR_ I took a chance with the decendant `<svg>` classname _`jss109`_ which initially looked dynamic to me. Still I took a chance.

Comment: I get it - i think. Thank you once again!